# Python: Print pdf file using reportlab

Tags: python, pdf, printing, reportlab

i simply want to print a .pdf file that i imported via reportlab.

however, in the reportlab docs, i can't find any method referring to print the actual .pdf

is there a way to do something similar to this? (pseudo code):

```
c = canvas.Canvas("hello.pdf")
c.drawString(100,750, "this is a test")
c.showPage()
c.save()
print(c)
```

i know that .pdf files are in binary format, so i need to convert it to a printable one, but i really don't know how to do this.

This question is not a duplicate. I'm trying to achieve this using Linux. The already answered question is about windows, i can't use some of the packages mentioned there.